# Xcode - Dropbox - NSMutabledictionary

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I'm iterating through the user's Dropbox content (using the loadedMetaData delegate) in order to get information about all files and folder names present in the user's dropbox (I need this so that I cab download all necessary data to the Documents folder of the app for offline use). The information shall be stored in an NSMutabledirectionary where "key = folder-name" and the object is always an array containing all files inside the folder. I'm doing this:

```
-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata
{

    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        //subfolders are loaded into array
        for (DBMetadata *directory in metadata.contents) {
            if (directory.isDirectory)
            {
                [directoryList addObject:directory.filename];
                //
            }
        }

        //files are loaded according loadmeta-folder (first run is root folder)
        [fileList removeAllObjects];
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
            if (!file.isDirectory)
            {
                NSLog(@"Directy is called %@", metadata.path);
                //NSLog(@"%@ was last changed %@", file.filename, file.lastModifiedDate);
                [fileList addObject:file.filename];
                [fileRevisionDates addObject:file.lastModifiedDate];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Key is called %@", metadata.path);


        //This is where I store the information in the dictionary
        [subFolderContent setValue:fileList forKey:metadata.path];
        //loadmetadata for all sub-folders
        for (int i = 0; i < directoryList.count; i++) {
            [restClient loadMetadata:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/TestFolder/%@/", [directoryList objectAtIndex:i]]];
        }
    }
}
```

Now this basically works, but of course, every time the array "fileList" is updated, all values for each key in the dictionary are updated accordingly... What am I missing? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!
Tom

Comment: You only ever create one `fileList`, apparently. A dictionary contains references to *objects*.  If you want unique values you need unique objects.

Comment: Hey, I see my problem, but I'm wondering how to create unique objects: I can't alloc the variables if I don't know beforehand how many I will need for each different user... You know what I mean?

Comment: Allocate them as you need them.  No need for a global pointer -- just allocate locally, put into the dictionary, and be done with it.

Comment: Sorry to be persistent, but could you maybe provide a quick code example? This is exactly my problem... An array needs a name, right (NsArray *fileListx = etc)? But how can I allocate fileList1, fileList2, fileList3 dynamically (100 folders would mean fileList99...). Think I'm missing something important here ;-) Thanks!

Comment: iOS objects don't have names.  Pointers have names, not the things they point to.  This is elementary object-oriented programming stuff that you should have down cold before you start mucking with Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for the "inputs", I am learning as I'm playing around...

Comment: If you try to learn Objective-C and you do not first understand basic O-O principles you pick up a lot of misconceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some rough code that *might* work. (I haven't tested it at all.) To answer your direct question, note that I'm initializing a new `fileList` in this method instead of having a global one somewhere else. This is what the commenters above were getting at.

I also did a little cleanup:

1. There's no need to keep the list of directories in an array and then call `loadMetadata` on each later. You can just call `loadMetadata` on each directory as you see it.
2. I deleted `fileRevisionDates` since it didn't seem usable in its current state. (I guess it was literally an array of dates? You probably need an NSMutableDictionary instead.)
3. I fixed the path construction on the recursive call to `loadMetadata`. If a user's Dropbox contained a directory like `/foo/bar/baz`, it looked like your code would try to get metadata on a path like `/TestFolder/baz`. I think the change I made will take care of that.

Again, I haven't tested this code at all (and my Objective-C is not very good), so there may be bugs/typos. Others should feel free to suggest edits:

```
-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        NSMutableArray *fileList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (DBMetadata *entry in metadata.contents) {
            if (entry.isDirectory) {
                [restClient loadMetadata:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", metadata.path, entry.filename]];
            }
            else {
                [fileList addObject:entry.filename];
            }
        }
        [subFolderContent setValue:fileList forKey:metadata.path];
    }
}
```

Finally, please note that this is not a great way to enumerate the contents of a user's Dropbox. See https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/efficiently-enumerating-dropbox-with-delta/ for the preferred approach, which is to use the `/delta` endpoint.